# Python: Issues with packages

Tags: python, package

I am currently learning how to work packages with Python but there still on thing I cannot understand.

My application is broken down like this (I made sure to add a __init __.py file in every single directory)

> Home Directory
>
> ____sub folder1
>
> ____sub folder2
>
> ____sub folder3

When I try to access scripts top down or within the same directory it works great. However, when I try to call a script in the **sub folder2** through the **sub folder1**, I get the following error:

```
from sub_folder1 import blablabla

ImportError: No module named blablabla
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: try `__init__.py` instead of `init.py`

Comment: That is the one, but somehow StackOverFlow hides the underlines :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
from ..sub_folder1 import blablabla
```

should work when you are in sub_folder2

Comment: ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py ?

Answer (score 0):

If you will create a new project in django e.g. testDjango16 and 2 apps inside it lets say utility and core it will have the below structure as shown.

[image]

Then you can refer any app inside other as

```
from testDjango16.utility import models
```

in lets say core app, in this way everything will work.

for creating a new project `django-admin.py startprojct testDjango16`
and to create a new app you should use
 `djang-admin.py startapp core` or `python manage.py startapp core`